# How to redirect two different outputs to one file in linux

Tags: redirect, output

I am having a mysql command :-
 "mysql -uroot -pxxx -e "use dbname; select * from tablename;" | wc -l"
whose ouput is "23" like this i'm having multiple tablename from which i need figures and i want to re-direct those figures in a file like this:

```
"table1 = 23"
"table2 = 25"
"table3 = 45"
```

I was hoping to use for loop or while loop but no success so far.

Comment: Instead of having your database barf out all of its data and counting the lines, you should consider doing what you want inside a query. something like `SELECT 'table1' AS table_label, COUNT(*) AS table_size FROM table1 UNION SELECT 'table2', COUNT(*) FROM table2 UNION SELECT 'table3', COUNT(*) FROM table3...`

Answer (score 0):

you could add `>> outputfile.txt` to the end of your command, making it something like:

```
mysql -uroot -pxxx -e "use dbname; select * from tablename;" | wc -l >> outputfile.txt
```

the `>>` operator tells the shell to append the output to the named file (a single `>` would overwrite the file instead). This way, multiple calls would append to the same file, getting you something like what you're looking for.

**HOWEVER**, As I said in my comment, I think that you should let the database do the thing that databases are good at (I.E. aggregating and manipulating data). you could craft a query to count the rows int multiple tables, in mysql that could look something like this:

```
SELECT 'table1' AS table_label, COUNT(*) AS table_size FROM table1 
UNION SELECT 'table2', COUNT(*) FROM table2 
UNION SELECT 'table3', COUNT(*) FROM table3
```

Comment: Hey Thanks this should meet my requirement

Comment: I have tried your query but i'm getting results like this